# add text file and take string randomly from it

Tags: java, string, user-interface, random, text-files

basically i have to add a textfile to my program and be able to take strings randomly from the text file so to do the other functions. to be able to play the hangman game. anybody help would be very welcome. find my code below how to add to it..

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ImageIcon imgs[];
    public JButton btns[];
    public String msgs[];
    public int ran;
    public int err;
    public String res[];

    public Main() {
        initComponents();
        imgs = new ImageIcon[6];
        btns = new JButton[27];
        msgs = new String[20];

        //Images of the young man hanged
        imgs[0] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Hangnam/im1.jpg"));
        imgs[1] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Hangnam/im2.jpg"));
        imgs[2] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Hangnam/im3.jpg"));
        imgs[3] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Hangnam/im4.jpg"));
        imgs[4] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Hangnam/im5.jpg"));
        imgs[5] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Hangnam/im6.jpg"));

        //Buttons for letters
        btns[1] = jButton2;
        btns[2] = jButton3;
        btns[3] = jButton4;
        btns[4] = jButton5;
        btns[5] = jButton6;
        btns[6] = jButton7;
        btns[7] = jButton8;
        btns[8] = jButton9;
        btns[9] = jButton10;
        btns[10] = jButton11;
        btns[11] = jButton12;
        btns[12] = jButton13;
        btns[13] = jButton14;
        btns[14] = jButton15;
        btns[15] = jButton16;
        btns[16] = jButton17;
        btns[17] = jButton18;
        btns[18] = jButton19;
        btns[19] = jButton20;
        btns[20] = jButton21;
        btns[21] = jButton22;
        btns[22] = jButton23;
        btns[23] = jButton24;
        btns[24] = jButton25;
        btns[25] = jButton26;
        btns[26] = jButton27;

        //words to guess
        msgs[0] = "understanding".toUpperCase();
        msgs[1] = "proliferation".toUpperCase();
        msgs[2] = "University".toUpperCase();
        msgs[3] = "Academic".toUpperCase();
        msgs[4] = "Atlas".toUpperCase();
        msgs[5] = "Tigres".toUpperCase();
        msgs[6] = "baby".toUpperCase();
        msgs[7] = "pumpy".toUpperCase();
        msgs[8] = "jump".toUpperCase();
        msgs[9] = "fun".toUpperCase();
        msgs[10] = "love".toUpperCase();
        msgs[11] = "something".toUpperCase();
        msgs[12] = "sometime".toUpperCase();
        msgs[13] = "mauritian".toUpperCase();
        msgs[14] = "lovers".toUpperCase();
        msgs[15] = "timetravel".toUpperCase();
        msgs[16] = "political".toUpperCase();
        msgs[17] = "psychologist".toUpperCase();
        msgs[18] = "rodrigues".toUpperCase();
        msgs[19] = "jackfruit".toUpperCase();


        //An event is assigned to each letter to check that it exists in the word to guess
        for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) {
            btns[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    checkLetter(e);
                }
            });
        }
        start();
    }

    //Function to start the game parameters or start a new game
    public void start() {
        //ERRORES EN 0
        err = 0;
        jButton1.setIcon(imgs[0]);
        jTextPane1.setText("");
        //To activate the letters on the board
        for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) {
            btns[i].setEnabled(true);
        }
        //To generate a word randomly
        ran = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * ((msgs.length - 1) + 1));
        //SEPARATE THE MESSAGE BY WORDS
        String pal[] = msgs[ran].split(" ");
        res = new String[msgs[ran].length() + 1];
        int j = 0;
        // Will be the word that go under the letters as a separation_
        for (String pal1 : pal) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pal1.length(); i++) {
                jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText() + "_ ");
                res[j++] = "_";
            }
            jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText() + "\n");
            res[j++] = " ";
        }
    }

    //When pressing a letter, this will be searched if it belongs to the word, otherwise mark it as error
    public void checkLetter(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton bt = (JButton) e.getSource();
        char c[];
        //Look for the letter in the word after it has been pressed
        for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) {
            if (bt == btns[i]) {
                //The key is initialized
                c = Character.toChars(64 + i);
                //Check if the letter is in the sentence
                boolean esta = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < msgs[ran].length(); j++) {
                    if (c[0] == msgs[ran].charAt(j)) {
                        res[j] = c[0] + "";
                        esta = true;
                    }
                }
                //IF THE LETTER IS IN THE MESSAGE IS SHOWN ON THE TEXTPANEL
                if (esta) {
                    jTextPane1.setText("");
                    for (String re : res) {
                        if (" ".equals(re)) {
                            jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText() + "\n");
                        } else {
                            jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText() + re + " ");
                        }
                    }
                    //Makes a check of the remaining letters and missing, in case there are no letters will be a winner
                    boolean gano = true;
                    for (String re : res) {
                        if (re.equals("_")) {
                            gano = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //To be correct a message is displayed and the game is restarted
                    if (gano) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Congratulation you won xD!!!");
                        start();
                        return;
                    }
                    //IF THE LETTER IS NOT IN THE MESSAGE, THE ERROR IS INCREASED AND THE IMAGE IS CHANGED
                } else {
                    jButton1.setIcon(imgs[++err]);
                    //IF THE 5 try ARE REACHED THEN THE GAME IS MISSED AND THE MESSAGE IS MADE:
                    if (err == 5) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sorry you lose"+"\n"+"Please Try Again, the answer is: \n" + msgs[ran]);
                        start();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //This is the line that deactivates the letters after being used
                bt.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ? You don't know how to read files, store the results in an array, generate a random index, what ? You're not expecting us to do the entire thing, are you ?

Comment: I agree.  This question *reads* like a request for us to write the code for you.  That is really not the point of homework.

Comment: actually my homework is done here.. this program runs perfectly fine.. still i want to learn how to add a textfile in my program and the program randomly takes words from a text file instead of an array.

Comment: or if you could point me to some documentation which can help me out. will be awsome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple program to get words from a random place in a text file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "/Users/[YOUR_NAME]/Desktop/words.txt"; //change to location of file
    File wordList = new File(fileName);
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new Scanner(wordList);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file \"" + fileName + "\" not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String word = reader.nextLine();
        words.add(word);
    }

    int place = rand.nextInt(words.size());
    String s = words.get(place);
    System.out.println("Random word from file: " + s);
}
```

Just incorporate it into your code. You may have to make some minor changes, but this will give you the answer.